# Error when payment processing using Realex

Tags: gwt, payment-gateway, realex-payments-api

I am working on payment processing using Realex with GWT

But at the last step it gives me following error message

> Using test system. Please use pre-approved test cards ONLY

Please help me.

Comment: Check their documentation or ask them for a test card number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most payment processors i've seen use one of two approaches:

- Have a "test mode" setting in the account, and a "test mode" variable in the gateway, and only consider the charge live if neither one indicates test mode.  (IIRC authorize.net works like this)  OR
- Have different URLs for test vs live charges.  (I'm thinking Paypal works like this...at least their IPN stuff does.)

Make sure you're using a "live" url, and that the account itself is not set for test mode.

Answer (score 3):

Your account is in test mode so you must use test credit card numbers. These are provided by Realex.

Comment: Which are? Is there some official info about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Realex's test card numbers [here](https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/technical-resources/test-card). Make sure you only use the test cards in test mode, pointing at the sandbox address - https://api.sandbox.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi